# Miglayout: Unable to use it with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, miglayout

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

This is my code.
I am getting the compiler error

The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
and 
The method `setLayout(LayoutManager)` in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (MigLayout)

I have configured the Miglayout.jar in my build path.
I can see it under -preferences>javabuildpath>libraries

can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you show any initiative?  It took about ten seconds to find the [Java Docs for MigLayout](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/javadoc/net/miginfocom/swt/MigLayout.html) and see that it does not implement layout manager.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanx for the quick reply. I have also tried  -1 
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout()); And i get the same error. The main issue here is " org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout cannot be resolved It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thank you for the API link; I'd not previously noticed how `MiGLayout` managed the [Swing](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/javadoc/net/miginfocom/swing/package-summary.html)/[SWT](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/javadoc/net/miginfocom/swt/package-summary.html) dichotomy in (roughly) parallel packages.

Comment: Of course you get the same error by trying to pass the same non-layout manager in the JPanel in the constructor or in the setter.

Comment: @trashgod  Huh.  It was pure luck that Google landed on that version of the `MigLayout`.  When I saw it in relation to the compilation error, I entered my comment.  Kudos.  OP.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Swing, you probably want to import `net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout`, rather than `net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout`.

Comment: Thank u for the reply.It works now.And @Andrew it works when i use panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
after i import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes I'll delete all imports use `Source > Organize Imports` to see the conflicts. Kudos to Andrew for the insightful link.

Comment: import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout  is not working in my case, i import jar file and build path successfully..